# Call C# from unmanaged C++ Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, c++, windows-phone-8

I have a problem with access to some system functions on Windows Phone 8 (I need to get phone ID or ANID2 in native C++). Because official API does not provide those ID in C++, I have to make separate project in C# (where ANID2 is working).

And now I have problem to call this C# function from unmanaged C++. I tried to call COM object and import tlb file, but with no success (intellisence says "cannot open .....tlh file" and when I try to compile it says that cannot include `olectl.h`). I guess it should be possible to do this with WRL, but I'm doing probably something wrong.

Or is there any other way to the a unique ID? All I need to get is unique ID of the phone (or ID of logged user) in unmanaged C++.

Comment: You can't windows phone doesn't support this. You need to be a first of second party to access this kind of information.

Comment: When user make in-app purchase I need to log this to server and then offer him some additional content - all this has to be based on user ID/phone ID/some unique ID

Comment: We did this by generating a GUID and saving this in roaming storage. This way it is a unique ID for the application for the user.

Comment: Even across multiple devices

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but this way is not much secure. If somebody copy data from roaming storage and share it, it will be much bigger problem.

Comment: I found one more option - when user make in-app purchase, I will get secure receipt from MS servers with PublisherDeviceId and also with PublisherUserId. I can store one of those ID on phone and our server also can work with this receipt.